# Из-за чего может не выводиться print_r, dump_var и не срабатывает хук init? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Перехватываю хук в файле *functions.php*:

```
add_action( 'init', 'test_init');
function test_init()
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r('Hello');
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Не выводит на главной странице, а на остальных страницах выводит. Почему? Может есть какой-то способ отменять действие хука, например, на главной странице?

Что еще я выяснил, если добавить в самый корневой файл *index.php* какой нибудь вывод через `print_r`, `var_dump`, Ничего не показывает. Почему?

`WP_DEBUG` включен

Answer (score 1):

Отменить действие события init нельзя - без него не запустится сайт.

Следовательно, раз ваша функция на событие init работает где-то (а вот этот код, что вы привели, не может не работать), она работает везде. Возможно, разметка на главной такова, что скрывает вывод `<pre>Hello</pre>` под каким-то блоками. Проверьте код страницы в инспекторе браузера, в секции Elements поиском наберите `<pre` и посмотрите, что будет найдено.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На `pre` ничего не повешено. Тут дело в чем-то другом. Например, сейчас у меня все показывает, причем показывает в _Chrome_, а в _Firefox_ нет. (

Comment: Не на `pre` именно, но вывод может перекрываться другим выводом. Проверка через echo всегда очень плохая, особенно на стадии init. Поставьте отладчик - phpStorm или хотя бы плагин WP PHP Console, и смотрите результат отладки там.

Comment: За плагин спасибо, щас гляну. А почему в _Chrome_ все ок, а _Firefox_ нет?

Comment: Работа php производится на сервере, каким вы потом браузером это смотрите - вообще дело десятое. Раз в браузерах по-разному отображается, значит, разметка кривая, и это ещё одно подтверждение моему ответу. Проблема не в хуке init,

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился. Была проблема связанная с работой плагина *WP Fastest Cache*. После того, как я его отключил все заработало. Начал работать print_r, dump_var и хук init.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. "Дело было не в бабине ..." - недостаточно для квалифицированного ответа.

Comment: Ну что за манера - задавать вопросы, не вычленив проблему. Как вообще кто-то может догадаться о наличии у вас малоизвестного плагина кеширования?

Comment: Извини, сам не знал, что это может быть связано с кешированием.